# Is there a reasonably easy way to write local (not instrumented) tests of ViewModel with Room database inside on Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

I created an Android Compose app. It has some `MyViewModel(db: MyRoomDatabase)` class. Room DAO is suspend. I'm thinking to write local (not instrumented) tests of this view-model class using real (not mocked) but in-memory Room database instance. Would it it be achievable with reasonable effort like mocking a few methods/classes or I will have to mock dozens of tricky methods inside of `Context`, `Looper`, `Handler` etc. and the whole idea is just wrong and I should simply stick with instrumented tests?

Comment: You can only instantiate an actual room database if you have a context object. This can only be done for instrumentation tests. You can also try Robolectric if you really need to test room. \

Comment: I can mock context. The question is if the number of things to mock will be too high.

Comment: I don't think you can use a mocked context to create a room database instance. You will need the actual thing or the closest from Robolectric